# A First-Order Trigonometric ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Original problem:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin x + y\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$$

So I realized that the left side is $(xy)'$. And after integrating both sides to $x$ I got $y=-\cos(x)/4\sin(x)$.
However the official answer from my teacher shows that the result is $(1-\cos(x))/4\sin(x)$. I am very confused and is it possible that someone help me correct my mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. I suggest you learn how to write mathematical expressions in MathJax, change your title to one that directly reflects the essence of your question, and try to make your picture directly accessible to the reader. There are other rules and conventions in this math forum, but you will soon get used to them by practicing. Good luck.

Comment: @Wombat Thanks for telling, is there anywhere I can learn how to change question setting to directly show picture or where to find MathJax?

Comment: @JindaNation I've submitted an edit to change the equations to MathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1108193) is a MathJax tutorial for future reference.

Comment: Did your teacher meant to say $\dfrac{1 - 2\cos^2{x}}{4\sin{x}}$ instead of $\dfrac{1 - \cos{x}}{4\sin{x}}$?

Answer (score 3):

So our ODE is
$$y'\sin x + y\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2x\,\text{.}$$
You are correct that by applying the product rule $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ to the left-hand side we achieve
$$(y \sin x)' = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2x\,\text{.}$$
Integrating both sides $\mathrm{d}x$, we get
$$y \sin x = -\frac{1}{4}\cos(2x) + C\,\text{,}$$
and allowing the constant of integration to be scaled,
$$y(x) = \frac{C-\cos 2x}{4 \sin x}\,\text{.}$$

From here, I'm not sure how either you or your teacher eliminated the factor of two in the argument of the cosine function. Further, the only way to select a value for the constant of integration is to provide some constraint on $y$ like an initial value.

Comment: great great, this is exactly what I think I missed. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

Two points.  First the problem CAN'T be what you say because the solution to the problem you give must include an arbitrary constant and neither the solution you give nor what you call the "official solution" have one. There must be some "additional condition" you have not given.

Yes,$\frac{dy}{dx}sin(x)+ y cos(x)$ IS $\frac{d(ysin(x)}{dx}$ so
$\frac{d(y sin(x))}{dx}= \frac{1}{2}sin(2x)$
$y sin(x)= \frac{1}{2}\int sin(2x)dx$
$y sin(x)= -\frac{1}{4} cos(x)+ C$
$y= \frac{-\frac{1}{4}cos(x)+ C}{sin(x)}$
You did not include the "constant of integration".

In order that what you call the "official solution" be correct, "C" must be 1 so we must have some additional condition such as [math]y(\pi/2)= 1[/math].

Comment: There's a mistake in the integration here. You're missing a factor of two in the argument of the $\cos$ function: $$\int \sin 2x\,\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{2} \cos(2x) + C\,\text{.}$$